# issue with _beginthreadex used with MFC class

Tags: mfc, beginthreadex

Can't use _beginthreadex in MFC
giving error as error C3861: '_beginthreadex': identifier not found
beginthreadex working fine without MFC code.

Edit:Issue was with file inclusion sequence and need was to use _beginthreadex

```
        // EventsHandshakeDlg.cpp : implementation file
            //
            #include <crtdefs.h>
            #include <process.h>
            #include"windowsx.h"
            #include "stdafx.h"
    unsigned int __stdcall/*AFX_THREADPROC*/ /*__cdecl*/ Server(void *iData)
                {

                }
            // CEventsHandshakeDlg dialogCEventsHandshakeDlg::CEventsHandshakeDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
                : CDialog(CEventsHandshakeDlg::IDD, pParent)
            {
                m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
            }
        BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CEventsHandshakeDlg, CDialog)
                ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
                ON_WM_PAINT()
                ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
                //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
                ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BTN_REVERSE, &CEventsHandshakeDlg::OnBnClickedBtnReverse)
            END_MESSAGE_MAP()



            // CEventsHandshakeDlg message handlers

            BOOL CEventsHandshakeDlg::OnInitDialog()
            {

                // TODO: Add extra initialization here

                return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
            }

          void CEventsHandshakeDlg::OnBnClickedBtnReverse()
                {unsigned int threadId = 0;
                HANDLE Thread =(HANDLE)_beginthreadex(
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    &/*CEventsHandshakeDlg::*/Server/*(void *iData)*/,
                    NULL,
                    0,
                    &threadId
                    );
}
```

Comment: Please post **relevant** code only. There really is too much unrelated code in your question to make it useful.

Comment: I will be careful next time.

Comment: What keeps you from being careful this time? You can still [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34568439/edit) your question, to make it more useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually `AfxBeginThread()` is used in MFC. Are you sure you need `_beginthreadex()`? All your parameters seem like defaults.

You might want to check the order of your `#includes` and the contents of `stdafx.h` and/or check your include directories. You also need to include `<process.h>` *after* `stdafx.h`. That might fix it.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Danny_ds problem solved when process.h is included after stdafx.h. I know that AfxBeginThread() is used but needed to use beginthreadex.